# Changing points into hexagon polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polygon-creation, geometry-conversion

In QGIS 3.18, I need to convert vector points into polygons for a client and there was a plugin that did this in QGIS 2 but I can't find anywhere in the questions that shows me how to do it.

The answer below created the polygon for me but it only gives me three types of areas, rectangles, circles and diamonds, the client wants the shape to be a hexagon based on the width field in the data. The data field has a metre amount as in 5 for 5 metres.

Comment: This doesn't seem to create polygons as the client requires

Comment: Sorry all good, had to play with it for a while to work out the settings, thanks.

Comment: It created the circles based on the data ok, but I need the shape to be a hexagon, still can't find anything to do this.

Comment: I've added the parameter value to the answer to get a hexagon.

Comment: Here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/45216/107424

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an equivalent tool, namely ["Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rectangles-ovals-diamonds), in the QGIS's Toolbox(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) under `Vector geometry`.

Set `Shape` as `Oval` and `Segments` value as `6` to get a hexagon.

[image]