# Changing polygon circles to hexagons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, polygon-creation, geometry-conversion

I received an answer to [Changing Points into Hexagon-Polygons using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396503), which enabled me to change the point to polygons using the "Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds" tool, which I used circles.

My client wants the shape to be a hexagon based on the width field in the data. The data field has a meter amount as in 5 for 5 meters.

Is there any way to make the circle a hexagon?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 19):

Yes, try to use the [`make_regular_polygon()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#make-regular-polygon) via the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Let's assume there is a layer *'Polygon'* with circles, see image below.

[image: input]
*violet points are just the base for circles*

In the "Geometry by expression" window use a formula for creating hexagons in *'Geometry expression'* field accordingly for

[image: tool_window]

#### inscribed

with this expression

```
make_regular_polygon(centroid($geometry), point_on_surface(boundary($geometry)), 6, 0)
```

and get the output
[image: inscribed]

#### circumscribed

with this expression

```
make_regular_polygon(centroid($geometry), point_on_surface(boundary($geometry)), 6, 1)
```

and get the output
[image: circumscribed]

Answer (score 10):

You can get hexagons from circles using [Centroids](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=rectangles%20ovals%20diamonds#centroids) and [Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=rectangles%20ovals%20diamonds#rectangles-ovals-diamonds) tools, consecutively.

"Centroids" tool generates centroids, of course. New "Centroids" layer has all columns of "Circles" layer. Then, you can generate hexagons based on `Width` field using "Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds" tool as in the image.

1. Shape: `Oval`
2. Width/Height: Click "Data defined override" button > Field > `Width`
3. Segments: `6`

[image]

I assume your data uses a projected coordinate system. In case of geographic, this method does not work.