# Transforming all polygons into circles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, polygon-creation, circle

I want to change the shape of all polygons within a layer into circles and maintain their original size. All polygons are different sizes and shapes at the moment, based on the extent of wind power sites.

I have not found a way how to actually create new, circular polygons at all. It seem like *"Geometry by expression"* could be a tool for this, but I have never used it and don't know the expression to achieve this.

Comment: There are several ideas that came into my mind: [1] ["Minimum bounding geometry"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#minimum-bounding-geometry) with *Minimum Enclosing Circle* or directly via the ["Minimum enclosing circles"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisminimumenclosingcircle)

Comment: [2] similar to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397032/changing-polygon-circles-to-hexagons-using-qgis/397037#397037) but using one of these expressions `minimal_circle($geometry, ...)` or `make_circle(centroid($geometry), ...)`. BTW what are the pre requirements for your radius?

Comment: What I want to do is to create the circles with the same area as the initial polygon in square meters (or other unit). These options only give circles around the initial polygon, resulting in a larger area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get circles with **equal area**, run *Geometry by expression* with:

```
make_circle(
    point_on_surface( $geometry ),   -- centroid( $geometry )
    sqrt( $area / pi() )
)
```

Here, the resulting circle centers on a point that is guaranteed to lie on the surface ([`point_on_surface()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#point-on-surface)) of the initial *Polygon*. This is likely a different location than the [`centroid()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#centroid), which is point-set weighted and may lie outside an irregular shape (or MultiPolygon) - you will have to decide which one suits best.

---

There are plenty of other *built-in* methods to create circles with relation to shape and size of the intial *Polygons*, including the [`minimal_circle()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#minimal-circle) function you can use inside the expression.

Comment: The last point and (many) more options are already covered by @Taras comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed. Great support!

Comment: @BERA ...I assumed `//` is galactic Basic for *inline comment*. I added a disclaimer.

Comment: The syntax for comments in QGIS expressions is the same as in SQL. Just use `--`, then you can just copy paste the code with no need to remove comments.

Answer (score 6):

If this is about symbology and you don't need to do any operations on the circles later on, you may use a [`centroid fill`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#fill-symbols).

You can force this point to be placed inside the polygon by checking the corresponding checkbox.

As to the [size of the point](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#vector-marker-symbols), you need to set the units to `map units`. Then head for the [data defined override](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#data-defined) of the symbol size. Hit `edit`, then enter the following: `sqrt($area/pi())*2`

This calculates the radius of a circle which has an area equal to the polygon it belongs to. `$area` grabs the area of the curent feature, `pi()` is Pi, and `sqrt()` returns the square root. We need to multiply this value by 2, since the size of point symbols in QGIS is defined by their diameter, not their radius.

The result looks as follows:

[image]

As said, this doesn't allow you to do geometrical operations on the circles, but it preserves you existing polygons (which in my opinion is more important in this business).

---

A word of advice: Overlaying features with value-indicating symbols is considered bad cartographic practice. Adding the value as a label, or using categories and a matching legend in order to indicate the value leads to better understanding of the map.

Comment: +1 for keeping base data intact. I'd try to use *Labels* though, and not render the geometries at all.