# Creating nested hex grids in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, cartography, polygon-creation, hexagonal-grid

I'm looking to replicate the kind of map [seen here](https://geohipster.com/2022/05/09/maps-and-mappers-of-the-2022-calendar-kate-berg-may/), where there are essentially multiple hex grids nested inside one another.

[image: map]
*Author :* Kate Berg

That example was made in ArcGIS Pro, whereas I'm working in QGIS 3.20. I have gotten as far as creating a couple of [separate hex grid layers](https://twitter.com/mattah353/status/1527297839570685952) and tried tinkering with the offsets of the top layer. However that only moves the top layer and doesn't have the shrinking effect I'm after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1.** Create a grid with the ["Create grid"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#create-grid) geoalgorithm

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Use the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

With the following expression:

```
make_regular_polygon(
    centroid($geometry),
    end_point(
        line_substring(
            make_line(
                point_on_surface(
                    boundary($geometry)
                    ),
                centroid($geometry)
                ),
            0,
            0.25 -- specify a step here 
            )
        ),
    6,
    0
    )
```

and get the output:

[image: result1]

In case if more hexagons are required apply the following expression:

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        generate_series(
            0,
            distance(centroid($geometry), point_on_surface(boundary($geometry))),
            0.25 -- specify a step here
            ),
        make_regular_polygon(
            centroid($geometry),
            end_point(
                line_substring(
                    make_line(
                        point_on_surface(
                            boundary($geometry)
                            ),
                        centroid($geometry)
                        ),
                    0,
                    @element 
                    )
                ),
            6,
            0
            )
        )
    )
```

and get a corresponding answer:

[image: result2]

Keep in mind that each output feature is a MultiPolygon, so the application of the ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) tool can be useful.

[image: single_part]

---

**References:**

- [Changing polygon circles to hexagons using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397032/changing-polygon-circles-to-hexagons-using-qgis/397037#397037)

Comment: This a really well-written and thorough answer, thanks.

Comment: I've also come across another solution which I will post seperately.

Answer (score 6):

Create an hexagonal grid then add some centroid fill using hexagonal symbol. you may control the colour of each symbol by using data override on each symbol.

[image]

Edit :

If you don't have hexagon symbol you may use this (just save the code as text file with a .svg extension :

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 113.4 113.4">
<polygon fill="param(fill) #9D9D9C" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke="param(outline)) #3C3C3B" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 0.25" stroke-miterlimit="1" points="78,19.9 99.2,56.7 78,93.5 35.4,93.5 14.2,56.7 35.4,19.9 "/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't see a hex symbol out-of-the box, but I'm sure I added a plug-in with additional svgs, so I'll check that out too.

Comment: on my version (3.24) the simple Marker include hexagon shape see my edit

Comment: Aha, I obviously need to update then, as ususing centroids like you suggested was one thing I wanted to try.

Comment: @MattHouston Iedited my answer to add SVG symbol

Answer (score 2):

Whilst @Taras has provided [a great answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/99589/taras) , I wanted to share another solution I came across - the ["Shape Tools"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/) plugin.

Not only could I edit the shape of my hexes, but I could also rotate them which was another issue I was having.

Specifically the tool I used was *'Geodesic transformations'*.